# PHP Compute data with complex criteria

Tags: php, sql

I have a table named **tblDueDetails** this contains all of the due details of my client.

Here is my table:

- Loanno (Char)
- DueDate (Date)
- DueCode (Char)
- StartDT (Date)
- EndDT (Date)
- DueAMT (Double)
- DuePD (Double)

Here is the code I made so far:

```
$duesquery = "SELECT DUEDT, DUECD, STARTDT, ENDDT, DUEAMT, DUEPD FROM LLDUEDET WHERE LOANNO = '". $loanno ."' AND DUEAMT != DUEPD";
$duessql = oci_parse($conn, $duesquery);
$duesexec = oci_execute($duessql);

if($duesexec){
    while($duesrow = oci_fetch_assoc($duessql)){
        $table .= '
        <tr>
             <td>'. date('m/d/Y', strtotime($duesrow['DUEDT'])) .'</td>
             <td>'. trim($duesrow['DUECD']) .'</td>
             <td>'. date('m/d/Y', strtotime($duesrow['STARTDT'])) .'</td>
             <td>'. date('m/d/Y', strtotime($duesrow['ENDDT'])) .'</td>
             <td>'. number_format(trim($duesrow['DUEAMT']), 2) .'</td>
             <td>'. number_format(trim($duesrow['DUEPD']), 2) .'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}
```

Here is my explanation:
- I need to get all the data when **DUEAMT** is not equals to **DUEPD**.
- However every time there is a **DUECD** equals to '**PRI**' and '**INT**' returned, I need to compute the **PENALTY** by adding the **DUEAMT** of **PRI** and **DUEAMT** of **INT** (Please see table)

Output of my SQL above:

```
 Due Date   |  Due |    Start Date   |  End Date |  Due Amount  |  Due Paid 
11/30/2019    PRI      10/30/2019     11/30/2019    19,546.62       0.00
11/30/2019    INT      10/30/2019     11/30/2019    10,808.38       1,062.86
11/30/2019    PEN      10/30/2019     11/30/2019    1,500.00        1,500.00
------- Insert Penalty Row Here ---------
12/30/2019    PRI      11/30/2020     12/30/2019    20,158.62       0.00
12/30/2019    INT      11/30/2020     12/30/2019    11,498.38       3,212.46
------- Insert Penalty Row Here ---------
1/03/2020     CCF      01/03/2020     01/03/2020    200.00          0.00
01/03/2020    CFR      01/03/2020     01/03/2020    729.17          0.00
```

My problem is how can I compute every **PENALTY** when the return data **DUECD** = **PRI** and **IND**

Comment: How are the `PEN` records linked to the `PRI` and `INT` records? And can you provide sample data for `PEN` records, and expected output?

Comment: @rohitvats please see my updated question I revised my question

Comment: And `PRI` and `INT` records are to be grouped together by `LOANNO` and `DUEDT`, correct?

Comment: @rohitvats yes but each DUECD are separate rows

Comment: Pls take a look at my answer, let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (you may change the penalty calculation in the subquery):

I have assumed that penalty only needs to be calculated if *both* `PRI` and `INT` records are present. If this assumption is incorrect, and you need to calculate penalty if *either* `PRI` or `INT` records are present, you can remove the `having count(*) = 2` from the query below.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=4e5186783b884ca6fa241616928b6773)**

```
select LOANNO, DUEDT, DUECD, STARTDT, ENDDT, DUEAMT, DUEPD
from
(
  SELECT LOANNO, DUEDT, DUECD, STARTDT, ENDDT, DUEAMT, DUEPD
         , case 
            when DUECD = 'PRI' then 1
            when DUECD = 'INT' then 2
            else 10
           end ord
  FROM LLDUEDET
  WHERE DUEAMT != DUEPD
   union all
  select pc.LOANNO, pc.DUEDT, pc.DUECD, pc.STARTDT, pc.ENDDT, pc.DUEAMT, coalesce(pa.DUEPD, 0.0) DUEPD
         ,3 ord
  from (
    select LOANNO, DUEDT, 'PEN' DUECD, STARTDT, ENDDT, ((SUM(DUEAMT)-SUM(DUEPD)) * 30) * .1 DUEAMT
    from LLDUEDET
    WHERE DUEAMT != DUEPD
    and DUECD in ('PRI', 'INT')
    group by LOANNO, DUEDT, STARTDT, ENDDT
    having count(*) = 2
  ) pc
  left join (
    select LOANNO, DUEDT, SUM(DUEPD) DUEPD
    from LLDUEDET
    where DUECD  = 'PEN'
    group by LOANNO, DUEDT
  ) pa on pa.loanno = pc.loanno and pa.duedt = pc.duedt
) s
order by LOANNO, DUEDT, ord
```

Comment: Your query is corrent but here is the actual formula in getting the penalty ((DUEAMT of PRI + DUEAMT of INT) - (DUEPD of PRI - DUEPD of INT) * 30) * 10%

Comment: Updated the query to use this formula, but are you sure it is correct? The penalty amount for the first two rows comes out to be `87876.42`

Comment: Yes thank you, there is a slight problem the problem in my database the penalty will be inserted when the customer/client paid the penalty. The problem is I need to get how much the customer paid

Comment: In your query you have  0.0 DUEPD instead of this the DUEPD should be how much the customer/client paid

Comment: Please see my updated question see the table to see what I am talking about

Comment: Query and demo updated with this new information. Pls upvote and accept if this helps.

Comment: please see my new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59927443/php-generate-future-data